# How do I stylize selected comments?

Tags: php, functions

I built my own theme from scratch, which has worked well for years, but I'm very rusty now on how I did it, and I could do with some help with my re-learning process.

When certain people comment (and it's rare!), I want to draw attention to it, so I've traditionally edited their comment manually, simply enclosing the comment content in an extra div which adds a style (a box). Clunky I know, but it worked.

Now Wordpress has started stripping out any divs as soon as I add them manually into the edit field of comments. So I need to automate the process. It will be easy, but I'm nervous with editing functions.php

**All I need to do is to surround** *comment_text();* **with...**

`<div class='highlight'> ... </div>`

**...if the url of the commenter matches a certain value (email address).** Nothing needed otherwise.

Any help on how to do this would be appreciated!

My comments code is:

```
// Custom markup for Comments
// Needs wp_list_comments("callback=my_custom_comments") in comments.php

function my_custom_comments($comment, $args, $depth) {
   $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
   echo '<li '; comment_class(); echo '>';

   if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') :
      echo '<em>' . _e('<span class="apologies">Your comment will be published when approved (a temporary measure - apologies)</span>') . '</em>';
   endif;
    //Start Custom Markup

    echo '<span id="comment-'; comment_ID(); echo '"></span><p class="comment-author">'; comment_author(); echo '</p>';

    //SOME IF-ELSE NEEDED HERE FOR SPECIFIC COMMENTER

    comment_text();

    echo '<p class="comment-date">'; comment_date(); edit_comment_link(__("Edit This"), ' | '); echo '</p>';
   //End Custom Markup
}
```

Comment: If you're using the stock WordPress `WP_Comment` object, then the email address is available in `$comment->comment_author_email`.

Comment: Thanks Pat, I'll give that a go!